# Cannot find gammu database schema

Tags: xampp, sms-gateway, gammu

I am trying to configure kalkun application. I have configure all the thing by following steps but I am not able to configure kalkun. I followed below steps:

```
sudo apt-get install gammu gammu-smsd
```

sudo gammu-config

sudo gammu-config

```
[gammu]

port = /dev/ttyUSB2
model = 
connection = at19200
synchronizetime = yes
logfile = 
logformat = textall
use_locking = 
gammuloc =
```

sudo gedit /etc/gammu-smsdrc

```
# Configuration file for Gammu SMS Daemon
[gammu]
# Please configure this!
port = /dev/ttyUSB2
connection = at19200
# Debugging
logformat = textall

# SMSD configuration, see gammu-smsdrc(5)
[smsd]
service = sql
driver = native_mysql
logfile = /var/log/smsdlog
# Increase for debugging information
debuglevel = 0

user = root
password = root
pc = localhost
database = kalkun
#runonreceive = /opt/lampp/htdocs/kalkun_0.7.1/scripts/daemon.php

# Paths where messages are stored
inboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/inbox/
outboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/outbox/
sentsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/sent/
errorsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/error/
```

I am using XAMPP for kalkun configuration. I have also follow the all the steps mentioned on https://github.com/back2arie/Kalkun/wiki/Installation but I don't know some how I am not able to get installation location and I get error **Cannot find gammu database schema.** Any one please help me to resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the Debian (and Ubuntu) packages the SQL files are located in `/usr/share/doc/gammu-smsd/examples/`.

Alternatively you can use [online documentation](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/mysql.html), however that covers latest version and the schema might not fit version you are using.